How to create carousel using FlatList , but visible part of next and prev slides
I need to create a slider in a mobile application using Expo and React Native. The challenge is to implement this slider using FlatList. The requirement is as follows:
We have 5 slides.

The first slide should partially reveal the next (second) slide.
Slides 2 to 4 should display a portion of both the previous and next
slides.
The fifth (last) slide should show a part of the previous (fourth)
slide.

import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, StyleSheet } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { walletService } from '../../../../services/Advertiser/Wallet/walletService';

import Header from '../../../../components/navigation/Header';
import PaymentMethodCard from '../../../../components/common/Cards/Wallet/PaymentMethodCard';

import { colors, fonts } from '../../../../styles/theme';

export default function Wallet() {
  const [paymentMethods, setPaymentMethods] = useState([]);
  const [accountBalance, setAccountBalance] = useState(0);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const flatListRef = useRef();

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    walletService.getPaymentMethods().then(setPaymentMethods);
    walletService.getAccountBalance().then(setAccountBalance);
  }, []);

  const handleSetDefault = (id) => {
    setPaymentMethods((prevMethods) => {
      const updatedMethods = prevMethods.map((method) => (method.id === id ? { ...method, isDefault: true } : { ...method, isDefault: false }));
      return [...updatedMethods.filter((method) => method.id === id), ...updatedMethods.filter((method) => method.id !== id)];
    });
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setPaymentMethods((prevMethods) => prevMethods.filter((method) => method.id !== id));
  };

  const onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => {
    if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
      setActiveIndex(viewableItems[0].index);
    }
  }).current;

  const viewConfigRef = useRef({ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50 }).current;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <Text style={styles.title}>Wallet</Text>

      <View style={styles.cardWrapper}>
        <FlatList
          ref={flatListRef}
          data={paymentMethods}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          snapToAlignment='start'
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
          viewabilityConfig={viewConfigRef}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <PaymentMethodCard
              method={item}
              onSetDefault={handleSetDefault}
              onDelete={handleDelete}
              isActive={index === activeIndex}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addButton}>
        <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>Add Payment Method</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <View style={styles.balanceCard}>
        <Text style={styles.balanceTitle}>Account balance</Text>
        <Text style={styles.balance}>${accountBalance.toFixed(2)}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.detailsButton}>
          <Text style={styles.detailsText}>Details</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.depositButton}>
        <Text style={styles.depositButtonText}>Deposit to account</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}


export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    borderRadius: 32,
    padding: 16,
  },
  flatListContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    gap: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: fonts.semiBold,
  },
});


import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
// import CryptoIcon from '../../../../assets/images/payment/crypto';
// import PaypalIcon from '../../../../assets/images/payment/paypal';
// import Dots from '../../../../assets/images/three-dots.svg';
// import CloseIcon from '../../../../assets/images/close';

import { colors, fonts } from '../../../../styles/theme';

export default function PaymentMethodCard({ method, onSetDefault, onDelete, isActive }) {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const getPaymentIcon = () => {
    switch (method.type) {
      case 'crypto':
        return <CryptoIcon />;
      case 'paypal':
        return <PaypalIcon />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  const maskAddress = (address) => {
    return address.slice(0, 6) + '****' + address.slice(-4);
  };

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.card, isActive && styles.activeCard]}>
      <View style={[styles.cardWrapper, method.isDefault && styles.defaultCard]}>
        <View style={styles.cardHeader}>
          <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
            {getPaymentIcon()}
            <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>{method.type === 'crypto' ? method.currency : 'PayPal'}</Text>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleModal} style={styles.threeDotWrapper}>
            <Dots />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {method.isDefault && <Text style={styles.defaultMethod}>Default payment method</Text>}
        <Text style={styles.cardNumber}>{method.type === 'crypto' ? maskAddress(method.address) : method.email}</Text>

        <Modal transparent={true} visible={modalVisible} animationType='slide'>
          <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
            <View style={styles.modalContent}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleModal}>
                <CloseIcon />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.modalButton}
                onPress={() => {
                  onSetDefault(method.id);
                  toggleModal();
                }}
              >
                <Text>Set as default payment method</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.modalButton}
                onPress={() => {
                  onDelete(method.id);
                  toggleModal();
                }}
              >
                <Text>Delete payment method</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export const walletService = {
  getPaymentMethods: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve([
          {
            id: 1,
            type: 'crypto',
            currency: 'USDC',
            address: '132',
            isDefault: true,
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            type: 'crypto',
            currency: 'Bitcoin',
            address: '123',
            isDefault: false,
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            type: 'paypal',
            email: 'user@example.com',
            isDefault: false,
          },
        ]);
      }, 500);
    });
  },

  getAccountBalance: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(10000.0);
      }, 500);
    });
  },

  getCryptoAccounts: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve([
          { name: 'Bitcoin', balance: 2.5 },
          { name: 'Ethereum', balance: 10.0 },
          { name: 'USDC', balance: 5000 },
        ]);
      }, 500);
    });
  },
};


========================================================================
Design
